# Is this a Code issue or a Unity input issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

noob here.

I am currently using a tutorial to make my first little 2d platformer.
With the use of a script, my character can move left and right. The issue I am having is 
getting the sprite to jump.

Below is my code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour


{
    public CharacterController2D Controller;
    public float RunSpeed = 40f;
    bool Jump = false;
    float horizontalMove = 0f;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * RunSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("This works");
            Jump = true;
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, false, Jump);
        Jump = false;
    }
}
```

The debug line does execute in the console my the Code registers my press of the space button, however, nothing happens to the little man on screen.

I hope someone can help.

Many Thanks,

Ellis

Answer (score 0):

the value you use in `Controller.Move()` to specify the force of the jump seems to be 0.

If you change `horizontalMove` to a public float you can assign a value to it in the unity editor or you can assign a value in the script.

Good luck.

EDIT:
Sorry, Immortality is right. You already set `horizontalMove`.

`Input.GetAxisRaw` can be -1,0 or 1. So `horizontalMove` can become -40, 0 or 40. Because you multiply in your controller arguments with Time.deltaTime - and deltaTime often being around 0.005 - your argument becauses roughly (-)0.2. I don't know what your controller does with that value but I guess that's the reason why you don't see anything. The value is just to small

Comment: No, the horizontal move should be set in the update method as op described. Assigning it from the inspector would make no sense at all.